# Restringir insert en PHP cuando se supera una fecha determinada

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo el siguiente formulario  y me gustaría restringir el `insert` si dichos datos superan  un fecha concreta, adjunto imagen para que puedan entenderme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, hay un campo *FECHA ALTA* y otro que no se ve denominado *FECHA EMISIÓN*. Mi pregunta es ¿cómo puedo restringir el `insert` si la fecha en la que se envían los datos supera a la fecha de alta?

Adjunto mi código actual :

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y no te sirve una condicional tipo: `if (::fecha_emisión:: > ::fecha_alta::) {}` ?

Comment: ¿En cuál formato recibes las fechas?

Comment: el formato del mi campon es  Type="date"

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Si copias/pegas el código en la pregunta, en vez de compartir capturas de pantalla, te podríamos ayudar a arreglar el problema de manera más sencilla y efectiva.

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `strtotime` obtienes la fecha actual y luego la comparas con la fecha que tienes en `fechaAlta`

```
<?php
  $hoy = strtotime(date("d-m-Y"));
  if ($hoy>$fechaAlta){
    echo "no se pueden enviar los datos";
  } else {
    //Acá el código que envía los datos a MySQL
  }
?>
```

Una alternativa es usar JavaScript o jQuery para validar la fecha sin esperar a que el usuario llene el formulario, lo que se traduce en una mejor experiencia de usuario `UX`.

*Te dejo la inquietud para que investigues un poco al respecto*.

Comment: No m funciona el codigo me da error

Comment: Que error te aparece? Recuerda que debes recibir la fecha de alta en la variable `$fechaAlta = $_POST["fechaAlta"]` o algo similar para poder compararla con `$hoy`. Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que tienes para poder comprender como está estructurado tu formulario y el envío de datos. Siempre en tus preguntas o comentarios agrega la mayor cantidad de detalles para poder reproducir tu caso y ayudarte a encontrar una solución apropiada.

Comment: aqui esta mi codigo original , alguna idea de porque no funciona con tu indicación ??

Comment: Dos cosas... 1- Revisa la respuesta de @AdolfoAlejandroAraya, el te da un ejemplo más completo. 2- En tus preguntas debes publicar el código como texto y no como imágenes. Revisa [como elaboro una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te des una idea de lo que te hablo.

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo un ejemplo completo de como deberías evaluar:

```
<form action="<?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
   <input name="fechaAlta"/><br>
   <input name="fechaEmision"/><br>
   <input type="submit" value="ok"/><br>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST["fechaEmision"]) && isset($_POST["fechaAlta"])){

    $fechaEmision = strtotime($_POST["fechaEmision"]);
    $fechaAlta = strtotime($_POST["fechaAlta"]);

    if($fechaEmision < $fechaAlta){
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
?>
```